# Send application to background with Qt

Tags: qt, background

I have two GUI applications.  The Master has to start the Slave.  The Master has to start on the foreground, the slave has to start on the background.  The slave has to come to the foreground later.

Is there a way to achieve this using Qt?

attempt so far:

```
... 
if( master() ) {
  window->show();
} else {
  window->showMinimized();
}
```

`showMinimized()` has the nasty side-effect that when the slave comes to the foreground first, it gets 'maximized'.

So is there a way to start an application *behind* another application?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to explicitly call `raise()` or `lower()` on the respective windows (see [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#raise)). It's possible that this may result in a momentary visual glitch though, where the window briefly appears then gets pushed to the back, which may or may not be acceptible. I was going to suggest using `QWidget::activateWindow()` to force an application to the foreground, but the [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#activateWindow) note that this is disallowed on Windows.

The other option would be to try to stop the widget becoming activated.  I've had a quick look at the Qt source of `QWidgetPrivate::show_sys()` (in `src/gui/kernel/qwidget_win.cpp`). There appears to be an attribute `Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating` which dictates how the window gets shown. It looks like this may solve your problem, eg see [Show window in Qt without stealing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966688/show-window-in-qt-without-stealing-focus)